# Wrong image path in liip imagine

Tags: symfony, liipimaginebundle, vichuploaderbundle

Im using vich uploader to upload images and oneup flysystem file abstraction. Also liip imagine bundle to make thumbnails.

The problem is that liip takes my oneup flysystem adapters local path and tries to find `uploads/58998d6502406.png` image in it. When i remove `uploads` prefix, then it works else throws source file not found exception.

Maybe i am missing something in my configuration?

Twig:
`<img src="{{ vich_uploader_asset(partner, 'imageFile') | imagine_filter('my_thumb') }}" />` (also tried with asset)

generated url:
`http://app.dev/media/cache/resolve/my_thumb/uploads/58998d6502406.png`

url that works:
`http://app.dev/media/cache/resolve/my_thumb/58998d6502406.png`

My configuration:

```
# OneupFlysystem Configuration
oneup_flysystem:
    adapters:
        uploads_adapter:
            local:
                directory: "%kernel.root_dir%/../web/uploads"
    filesystems:
        uploads_fs:
            adapter: uploads_adapter
            mount:   uploads_fs

# Vich uploader Configuration
vich_uploader:
    db_driver: orm
    storage:   flysystem
    mappings:
        partner_image:
            uri_prefix: /uploads
            upload_destination: uploads_fs
            namer: vich_uploader.namer_uniqid
            delete_on_remove: true
            delete_on_update: true
        news_image:
            uri_prefix: /uploads
            upload_destination: uploads_fs
            namer: vich_uploader.namer_uniqid
            delete_on_remove: true
            delete_on_update: true

# Liip imagine bundle Configuration
liip_imagine:
    loaders:
        uploaded_images:
            flysystem:
                filesystem_service: oneup_flysystem.uploads_fs_filesystem
    data_loader: uploaded_images
    filter_sets :
        my_thumb:
            filters:
                thumbnail: { size: [120, 90], mode: outbound }
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by changing `uri_prefix` in vich uploader config to empty string `uri_prefix: ""`